# Using Regex to parse String from input

Tags: java, regex

Here is my code to match a String like:

```
    String name = qualified.replaceAll(".*\\.(?=\\w+)", "");
```

Where it gets from input `org.myapp.TestData$RootEntity` a `TestData$RootEntity`

However I need to be able to get just the `RootEntity` part of the String. Effectively getting just this.

Input Strings:

```
com.domain.app.RootEntity

com.domain.app.TestData$RootEntity

com.domain.app.TestData$TestNested$RootEntity
```

And should be able to get `RootEntity`

Comment: use `string.lastIndexOf('$')`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this:

```
String name = qualified.replaceAll(".+?\\W", "");
```

`.*\\W` matches everything before `$` or `.` and replaces it with empty string.

Comment: For a input string "com.domain.app.RootEntity" it returns empty, it should return RootEntity

Comment: @xybrek, glad to have helped.

Answer (score 1):

Try with simple `String#lastIndexOf()`

```
    String qualified = "org.myapp.TestData$RootEntity";

    String name = qualified.substring(qualified.lastIndexOf('$') + 1);
```

---

Complete code

```
    String[] values = new String[] { "com.domain.app.RootEntity",
            "com.domain.app.TestData$RootEntity",
            "com.domain.app.TestData$TestNested$RootEntity" };

    for (String qualified : values) {
        int index = qualified.lastIndexOf('$');

        String name = null;
        if (index != -1) {
            name = qualified.substring(qualified.lastIndexOf('$') + 1);
        } else {
            name = qualified.substring(qualified.lastIndexOf('.') + 1);
        }

        System.out.println(name);
    }
```

output:

```
RootEntity
RootEntity
RootEntity
```

Answer (score 0):

Simple:

```
String resultString = qualified.replaceAll("(?m).*?(RootEntity)$", "$1");
```

Answer (score 0):

```
com.domain.app.RootEntity
com.domain.app.TestData$RootEntity
com.domain.app.TestData$TestNested$RootEntity
```

> And should be able to get `RootEntity`

In looks like you want to remove each part of name which has `.` or `$` after it like `app.` or `TestData$`.

If that is the case you can try

```
replaceAll("\\w+[.$]", "")
```

---

Demo

```
String[] data = {
        "com.domain.app.RootEntity",
        "com.domain.app.TestData$RootEntity",
        "com.domain.app.TestData$TestNested$RootEntity",
};
for (String s:data)
    System.out.println(s.replaceAll("\\w+[.$]", ""));
```

Output:

```
RootEntity
RootEntity
RootEntity
```